# Visual Studio Add-in project + WinForm + WPF ElmentHost

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, add-in

If I want to open a winform then that is ok, but I need to open a winform application with element host and that is wrong. The debugger can't find error, but I click the add-in button then do nothing.

Code in exec:

```
Form1 f1=new Form1();
f1.Show();
```

Code in winform:

```
        MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
        elementHost1.Child = mw;
```

References I think ok.

Comment: You cannot set a windows as child. You have to make a user control that's embedded in the form.

Comment: MainWindow is an UserControl